# update database on JTable cell change

Tags: java, jtable

I have a window that displays my data based on data in a table, but the trouble is that when I change and I click on the save button I get an error : Error:No value specified for parameter 1.

But I do not want to change all columns just the latest

```
enregistrer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                    int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
                    String sql = null;
                      try {
                        if(col==4)
                            sql = "UPDATE impaye" + "SET Impayé = ?" + "WHERE ID = ? "+ row;


                            preStat =(PreparedStatement) connexion.prepareStatement(sql);
                            preStat.setObject(1, table.getValueAt(row, col));
                            preStat.executeUpdate();
                                preStat.close();

                      } catch (SQLException insertException) {
                           System.out.println("Error:"+insertException.getMessage());
                      }

                    }

                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I do not want to change all columns just the latest

Well then you need to change your SQL. Currently your SQL updates all 4 columns.

If you only want to update a single column, then you need 4 SQL statements. The statement you use will be based on the index of the column that was changed.

Something like:

```
String sql = null;

if (col == 0)
    sql = "UPDATE impaye SET Date = ? " + row;
else if (col == 1)
    sql = "UPDATE impaye SET Débiteur = ? " + row);
else if
    ...

preStat =(PreparedStatement) connexion.prepareStatement(sql);
preStat.setObject(1, table.getValueAt(row, col));
preStat.executeUpdate();
```

I think you will also need a "where" clause in your SQL. I don't think you can just specify a row number (but I don't know much about SQL).

Comment: Since I tried to change but I have always an error : Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1

Comment: @Recay, I suggested your SQL was wrong. You need to read a book on SQL. You can't just specify "row". Usually you need a "where clause" to specify the row you want to update. I don't know the structure of your database or what the column names are so I can't give you the exact SQL. Check out more information about the "where" clause in this [SQL Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html). You can't code SQL if you don't have an SQL reference to get a book or find a good tutorial we are not here to write the SQL for you.

Comment: I changed and I added the where clause but I have this error : Error:SQL String can not be NULL

Comment: So fix the error!!! The message tells you String can't be null. So make sure the String is not null. We can't solve the problem for you. The problem is with the data in your String.